# jQuery datepicker disable user selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, selection

I have a jquery datepicker assigned to a div, I am currently using it to show a calendar only and do not want to be able to select any items on the datepicker.

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

edit: to clarify, I am using Jquery UI datepicker.
The user should not be able to select month, year, day etc, or get the hand icon.
I will still be able to assign selected dates, etc, with jquery

the datepicker calendar is always shown.

Comment: just to show the calendar and negate any event on it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745039/disable-selection-jquery-datepicker-field

Comment: yes, show the calendar and not have any onlick events.

Answer (score 5):

i have found that the solution to this problem is simply to disable all the dates with the function beforeShowDay.

ie

```
beforeShowDay: function (date) {return [false, ''];}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Datepicker have inbuilt disable function in them.
for jquery datepicker [Refer This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323285/dynamically-disable-jquery-datepicker-icon)

2) You can remove the binding attribute for a while temporarily.

3) You can even put mask on top of that div.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways are help full to disable user selection

```
 $('.datepicker').datepicker({

 }).on('show', function(e){
 $('.day').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
 });
```

second

```
 $('#datepicker-inline').datepicker({
     //Other options...
   beforeShowDay: function() {
     return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First create Textbox for date

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" class="datepicker"></p>
```

Then using JQuery we can achieve the disable feature

```
 $(".datepicker").datepicker({
      //Other Options
   }).attr('readonly', 'readonly');
```